# I don't want to click 'through' an Infobox

Tags: google-maps, mobile, infobox

I'm currently having issues with the google-maps-utility-library plugin for custom infoBoxes on a Google map.
I can successfully create a custom shaped infoBox as I want it to be. But on mobile devices (tested on Galaxy S2 and iPad) I can click through the infoBox. This is pretty annoying because it also happens when one touches the close button of the infobox and immediatly opens another markers infobox when there is one underneath the close button (happens very often on my map).

Does anyone know a way how to fix this?
My first thought was that it has to do with the enableEventPropagation flag but disabling eventpropagation seems to have no effect on mobile devices (and I need the events for other stuff).

Thanks in advance for your time reading and answering :)

Comment: Have a look at this - I think it should resolve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170244/google-maps-infobox-with-click-handlers-and-scrollbar

Comment: I'm having the same issue in chrome. Will report back if I find a fix for this, the link didn't really help in this specific case for me. I was able to disable scroll as the example said, but was not able to disable the user from clicking a marker behind the infobox.

Comment: I switched to using the infobubble plugin (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/)

This killed all clickevents. fixed that with the help of this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18114253/1885630