# jQuery UI Slider within google maps InfoBubble

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a custom InfoBubble that is holding two jQuery UI sliders to manipulate some data. I had no problems creating the Bubble and the Slider. Unfortunately, somewhere a mouse event seems to be prevented from bubbling to the slider.

I prepared a Fiddle to explain the behaviour: 
<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/frontender/pDFc3/52/)</kbd>

To reproduce the error, do the following:

```
1. Click on the slider knob
2. Move your mouse outside of the InfoBubble
3. Move your mouse to the left and right to use the slider
4. Move your mouse back to the info window and see the slider movement cease immediately.
```

Does anybody know where the event gets lost and how I could fix this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I invested quite a bit of time to find a solution to this. But I got it working now!

The problem lies within the InfoBubble code. All events are being prevented from bubbling up to the map, apparently to prevent Ghostclicks through the Bubble. Unfortunately this prevents also all other listeners from working properly.
The code snippet handling the events is found on line 808:

```
/**
 * Add events to stop propagation
 * @private
 */
InfoBubble.prototype.addEvents_ = function() {
  // We want to cancel all the events so they do not go to the map
  var events = ['mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mouseup',
      'mousewheel', 'DOMMouseScroll', 'touchstart', 'touchend', 'touchmove',
      'dblclick', 'contextmenu', 'click'];

  var bubble = this.bubble_;
  this.listeners_ = [];
  for (var i = 0, event; event = events[i]; i++) {
    this.listeners_.push(
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(bubble, event, function(e) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
      })
    );
  }
};
```

Now you could just remove the events from the array, that you want to use without much of an impact. I decided to take a softer approach and only allow those events, that I truly needed for my sliders (and links) to work:

```
InfoBubble.prototype.addEvents_ = function() {
  // bla bla code, see above
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(bubble, event, function(e) {
        // allow all mouseup-events
        if(e.type == 'mouseup') { return; }
        // allow click events from my button classes
        if(e.type == 'click' && $(e.fromElement).closest('.btn') ) { return; }
        // allow events that come from my jquery ui slider
        if( $(e.fromElement).is("div[class^='ui-slider-'],div[class*=' ui-slider-']") ) { return; }

        // else: do what you have to do
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
    );
  // bla bla code, see above
};
```

You can find a working example here: <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pDFc3/61/)**</kbd>

Comment: I have encountered exactly the same behaviour, but in my case it was Bootstrap dropdown and modal toggle... So thanks for workaround.